# Are we salvageable?

Tags: cipher, lateral-thinking, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

You wake up in a small room. The door is locked and there's no light other than 3 red glowing bulbs over a heavy iron door. Across the room you see a small table with a typewriter that doesn't seem to work anymore. You approach it and take a seat on a scruffy wodden stool, groaning deeply. Suddenly you feel your feet stumbling onto something soft and heavy below the table. You slowly get up again fearing the worst. You decide to have a short look, at least. 
Below the table there's a body wrapped up in pieces of cloth with its face turned towards the wall. A man about twice your age, his mouth still opened as if he was about to say something the moment he passed away. The little amount of light makes it almost impossible to see properly. In his right hand you find a small piece of paper...

[image: updated message]

```
8 ≠ 08

  d
8 13 4 8 10 // 10 07 8 8 0 // 09 16 5 09 0
```

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

Hints:

> • No image editing needed.
>  • No fancy tricks. Very simple mathematical operations are enough.

Comment: Am I in a the airhold of a submarine or spaceship maybe?

Comment: It may be worth noting that #32369 is OP's ID increased by 1. It is also ID of user [jchook](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32369/jchook)

Comment: Is the scribbled diagram on the paper an attempt to figure out the wiring logic of the lights? Attempting to change R to G (ie red to green)? Three greens would open the door?

Comment: The author of the note claims he did not succeed in opening the door, so unless he is a terrible liar, we should not follow his steps ;)

Comment: One of the things crossed out on the paper is "pqv". The red-lamp image on imgur is `pqvZn`. Make of that what you will.

Comment: I tried changing hue, brightness, saturation of pic and did not find anything hidden (please confirm)

Comment: One thing I noticed is that all three images lead to the same url link, so they appear identical.

Comment: I guess pqvZn - pqv is Zn, or Zinc, maybe...

Comment: It would be awesome if you were able to put some more "clues" on how to approach it within the puzzle itself without having to add hints. This puzzle seems interesting, but after such time with absolutely no progress I feel it starts loosing its charm.

Comment: looks like extra clues have been added to the picture. Highlighting of red and green lights, 8 != 08, and the `d` above the first set of numbers.

Comment: What I have to do now? Have to open the door? have to press a button? Whatever the simple mathematical operation is... what does the puzzle tells to do?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused, the tag enigmatic-puzzle: "Puzzles where the genre or solving strategy of the puzzle is not explicitly stated; puzzles where the puzzler must deduce what type of puzzle it is."..."The door is locked"..."the damn thing won't open"

Comment: @oleslaw [jchook](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32369/jchook) joined as the same time as OP...

Comment: I wonder how the 3 bulbs are glowing though they are not connected to the supply

Comment: I don't like asking for hints, but apparently we are stuck with this. I'm out of ideas after what I wrote. I've tried a couple more things but they lead nowhere. This looks like a good puzzle but there doesn't seem to be a good place to start. If you don't want to give more hints or if you want to wait a bit more say it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution (after some heavy hinting from the OP):

> [image: XdZhx]
>  [image: zxDhN]
>  [image: ygAIN]

Here's how you decode the cipher:

> You want to get three Imgur links to three images of green lamps. Each $5$ number group corresponds to one URL. Start from the original red lamp image URL ($pqvZn$), convert it to numeral ($a=1\dots$), add the numbers of each cipher and convert it back to letters (mod $26$) preserving the original capitalization (for example for the first one you get $xdzHx$) and then change the capitalization of each letter that doesn't correspond to a double digit number ($07$ is considered a double digit number and that's what the hint $8\neq 08$ is supposed to mean).

My opinion on the puzzle:

> This puzzle looked like it was well crafted, but the cipher is really bad. A good cipher should be capable of encoding any type of message and this one can't. For example you if one of the solutions had a $D$ as a second letter you wouldn't be able to encode it with this cipher because writing $13$ doesn't change the capitalization. All you can get $q\to d$.

Old (and wrong) line of reasoning:

> Start from the Red to Green image. I think this means what to open the door we need to turn those red light into green ones. How do we do this? By decrypting the message on the bottom on the paper. You can see that it is made by $15$ numbers divided into $3$ group of $5$ numbers. Also you can note (thanks @GarethMcCaughan)the string "pqv" that is the first three letters of the Imgur link of the red lights. Putting this all together makes me think that the solutions will be made of three Imgur link of three images of green lights that you get by assigning a value to each number of the code.
>
>  Each Imgur link is made of 5 characters that can be letters $a,\,\dots,\,z,\,A,\,\dots,\,Z$ or numbers $0,\,\dots,9$. Here is where I think the clue $8\neq 08$ fits. I think that $8$ means "this is an encoded letter" and "$08$" means "this is the number $8$ on the URL". This means that so far we got the three images:
>
>  - xxxxx.jpg
>  - x7xxx.jpg
>  - 9xx9x.jpg
>
>  Now, how do you decode the letters then? Since my hypothesis is that you need to change the red lights into the green ones I think you should start from the original image URL and change those letters by subtracting the cypher number from its value (a=1, b=2, ...). This might be confirmed by the $d$ over the number $13$. The original URL is pqvZn. If you take the second letter $q$ and you subtract $13$ you get $d$. Since all the three red lamp images are the same you need to start from the same URL in all the three cases.
>  If you do this for all the numbers here's what you get:
>
>  - hdrrd.jpg
>  - f7nrn.jpg
>  - 9aq9n.jpg
>
>  But none of those images actually exists. As you can see I'm obviously missing the capitalization of the letters. I don't know whether a letter will be lowercase or uppercase. If I preserve the capitalization of the original URL (so only the 4th letter will be uppercase) I still get nothing.

Comment: +1 for the efforts. The links could be made up of lower case letters as well. For me, the things noted are difficult to read really.It would be better if the OP can provide a little better version of it.

Comment: I am going through your image strings,  f7nrn.jpg does not have an existing solution of upper and lowercase letters.

f7nrn,F7nrn,f7nrn,F7nrn,f7Nrn,F7Nrn,f7Nrn,F7Nrn,f7nRn,F7nRn,f7nRn,F7nRn,f7NRn,F7NRn,f7NRn,F7NRn,f7nrN,F7nrN,f7nrN,F7nrN,f7NrN,F7NrN,f7NrN,F7NrN,f7nRN,F7nRN,f7nRN,F7nRN,f7NRN,F7NRN,f7NRN,F7NRN

Answer (score 0):

Based off of FrodCube's answer I am going through the iterations of possible images, I will edit this as I find more. My guess is that this is pure coincidence that this exists:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDrRd.jpg
>  the other strings given by FrodCube do not have existing images associated with them.